# how to view root /mnt/image files in linux server?

Tags: linux, opencart, document-root

I have stored all the images in server root directory Ex: "/mnt/image/pic.jpg" now i want to view this image in browser,but normally can access only inside /var/www/... how to achieve this.

Comment: Iam using Apache server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link the directories

`ln -s /mnt/images /var/www/images`

After that you can access to /var/www/images/pic1.jpg without any problem (check user and group permissions if you cannot access)

EDITED with @Anders advice

Don't forget to add `Options FollowSymLinks` if you are using Apache web server

Comment: And remember `Options FollowSymLinks`.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply let me check first.

Comment: Please tell me i am using Apache server and where to add 'Options FollowSymLinks' .

Comment: @user2496631 Check this url: http://superuser.com/questions/244245/how-do-i-get-apache-to-follow-symlinks

Comment: Sorry to bother this will not give me the solution,i am dynamically storing all the images in /mnt/images location and want to access the images only from this location.

Comment: Only from what location? /var/www/images? my answer show how to link directories, so if you save an image in /mnt/images it will be accesible through /var/www/images. If this is not the problem modify your question in order to explain clearly whats your problem please

Comment: @ sal00m : My problem is, i have 10GB space in /mnt/.. and 5GB space in /var/www/.. if i link the directory it will occupy the space in /var/www/.. but i dont want this, i just want to access the image from /mnt/... how please.

Comment: @ sal00m : Thanks a lot i done in revers and works perfect : ln -s /mnt/images /var/www/images

Comment: Oh god yes, i write it incorrect... sorry, i'll edit the answer to write it corrected